# Polycom VVX 600 VOIP phone taking almost 5 minutes to reconnect on secondary internet

Tags: voip, failover

We have 2 internet connections coming into our 1 firewall. 1 internet connection is a backup (or failover) internet connection. When our primary connection goes down, our firewall fails over to our backup connection fairly quickly. Within 30 seconds at the most. All of our devices reconnect as soon as the firewall is up, except for the VOIP phones, which can take 3-5 minutes. No firewall policies are blocking any of the VOIP traffic. I'm trying to figure out if there is a setting in the Polycom VVX 600 that will force a reconnection within 30-60 seconds. I cannot find anything on Polycom's website except 1 forum post that doesn't work. Our VOIP provider is just telling us to reboot our phones every time. Has anyone run into this issue that can point me in the right direction? Thank you.